# Automatically set to check if data is present in database

Tags: mysql, checkbox

I have a multiple checkboxes stored in one field of one table (stored as array). I have to get the whole array (which is working).I'd like to know how can I automatically set the checkbox if the data is present in database.

here's my code:

```
echo "&nbsp;<td><input id=\"services[]\" name=\"services[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$ser\"/>";
                                                      echo "<label for='services'>$ser</label><br>";
                                                      echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: I'm not aware of an *array* data type in MySQL. How are the checkbox values **actually** stored?

Comment: What I mean is that, i have imploded the data so it will be stored as a string. Sorry. @Phil

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 echo '<tr>'.
      '<td><input id="services" name="services[]" type="checkbox" value="$ser"' .($ser==1?'checked="on"':"").'/>'.
      '<label for="services">'.$ser.'</label><br>'.
      '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Whats the exact problem is now? What is value in $ser?

Comment: $ser = $record1['serName'];